# How do Inbox and Gmail actually interact?

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

I'm trying out Google's Inbox. There are a couple of new workflow features that don't seem to exist in Gmail:

1. Marking things as "done"
2. Pinning things (with optional reminder)

(Other features like "bundling" certain labels are just a different way of presenting existing features, I think.)

Is there a way to access these Inbox features from Gmail? Can you find whether something is "done" or "pinned"?

If not, these features seem useful if you switch 100% to using Inbox?

Answer (score 8):

From [How Inbox works with Gmail](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6098273):

- Marking something "Done" is the same as "Archiving" in Gmail
- Pinning something is *generally* equivalent to using the Gmail "Star"

Bundles are basically the categories that Gmail introduced last year, but with more of them and more granular. Creating your own bundles is generally equivalent to creating labels in Gmail *and* creating a filter to put messages there.

Comment: Hmm, that can't be quite right. You can "Done" things that aren't in the inbox - and they disappear (in Inbox). You can't archive something that's not in the inbox.

Comment: "Done" does indeed archive items. (I've seen it first hand.) That there is some other flag that is set by Inbox but isn't visible in Gmail isn't surprising.

Comment: When I open Done using Inbox, here is the note that appears: Anything you mark done is safely stored here. Emails you've previously archived are here, too.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Done = Archive + some Inbox flag.